# How pass RichText to TextField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need some parts of the text that can be edited - make it clickable, this can be implemented using standard `TextField` tools? I can pass to it RichText?

Comment: how do you like to edit the text? should be inline or will pop dialog with textFiled

Comment: Use Stack to put the RichText at Top and TextField at bottom, When you click RichText hide it and focus the TextField, When you click done button unfocus textfield and make RichText visible

Comment: @YeasinSheikh edit the text in the inline way, but if there is a piece of text on which you can click - will pop dialog

Comment: @BalajiRamadoss There can be a lot of text and I'm not sure that the boundaries will be calculated correctly, but I like this idea

Answer (score 0):

**Full widget**

```
class PopUpT extends StatefulWidget {
  PopUpT({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PopUpTState createState() => _PopUpTState();
}

class _PopUpTState extends State<PopUpT> {
  String changeableText = " Click to change this Text";
  late final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController(
      text: changeableText,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: "This is an example shows how to change inline Text "),
              TextSpan(
                text: changeableText,
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () async {
                    showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            TextField(
                              controller: controller,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  changeableText = controller.text;
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text("Done"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Text.rich - it does not have the ability to edit text using the keyboard. I meant that I need to click inside  [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html).

Comment: `TextFiled` doesn't have inline clickable property, you have to wrap it with `GestureDetector` and in result Full TextFiled will be clickable. can you include a gif or some image that you like to archive?

Comment: Android Native has a class `SpannableStringBuilder`  which allows you to wrap the part of text and make it clickable inside `textField` I need something similar. So that you can edit the text and click on it, but there is no such thing in the flutter